# merge xml files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, merge

I'd like to merge a few xml files.
The destination xml is slightly different then the source files. The destination file contains an aditional root element.

For example.

The destination xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customer ID="A0001" name="customername">
.....
.....
</customer>
```

Source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order number="00001">
    <.....>
    <.....>
    <.....>
</order>
```

Every source xml file needs to be inserted between `<customer ...>` and `</customer>`

The source files can be very large (e.g. 2 Gb).

I can write the destination xml file with the root element and read the source files using XmlTextReader and

```
string myOrder = textReader.ReadOuterXml();
                        writer.WriteRaw(myOrder );
```

Result (where every order is a different xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customer ID="A0001" name="customername">
    <order number="00001">
        <.....>
        <.....>
        <.....>
    </order>
    <order number="00002">
        <.....>
        <.....>
        <.....>
    </order>
    <order number="00003">
        <.....>
        <.....>
        <.....>
    </order>
</customer>
```

But i'm afraid of out of memory exeptions for the large files using ReadOuterXml().

Any suggestion ?

Comment: how big of each source file? 2G?

Comment: Do you need to do *any* actual processing of the files, other than skipping the XML declaration? Is it just a case of adding a prefix and a suffix, and the rest is just copying?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671958/reading-large-xml-documents-in-net

Comment: @Cuong Le: Yes sometimes even larger (can change that - out of my control)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Just need to merge all the source files (and skipping the xml declaration) and add <costumer> Thats all  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like in this particular case, assuming all the files are really using UTF-8, you can basically cheat. .NET 4 makes this particularly easy:

```
public void MergeFiles(string outputPath, string prefix, string suffix,
                       IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, prefix);
    var lines = files.SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file).Skip(1));
    File.AppendAllLines(outputPath, lines);
    File.AppendAllText(outputPath, suffix);
}
```

This isn't *quite* as efficient as it might be, as it'll open the output file three times - but it's written about as simply as I could make it. Note that `lines` here is lazy - this *won't* read the source files completely into memory; it'll read a line at a time.

It does *rely* on each file starting with the XML declaration and being in UTF-8 though. There are far more robust streaming approaches you could use, but if you're confident of your source format, this is very simple...

EDIT: Sample usage:

```
string prefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n"
              + "<customer ID=\"A0001\" name=\"customername\">";
MergeFiles("output.xml", prefix, "</customer>", sourceFiles);
```

Comment: I'm confused, how does the customer tag get into the output?

Comment: @Jodrell: You put that in the "prefix" part... I'll edit with an example.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I prefer the simplicity to the reader writer chaining I was preparing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry for my late response. I've been very busy. Nice solution. Works for me.