# There was an exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, xml, exception, out-of-memory

Good afternoon. 
When trying to process an XML file that weighs 556.109 KB and save the information in a database I get the following error:

`There was an exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.`

I get this error when you go to approx 89% of the document read. I have been monitoring the computer's RAM and still has space to be allocated when this exception occurs. Using a stacktrace tells me the following:

`in System.String.ConcatArray (String [] values​​, Int32 TotalLength) 
System.String.Concat (String [] values​​) 
in ConfigServicio.Form1.LeerXML (FileInfo fileLXML)`

Reading on various forums and at various information indicate that there is about computer memory, otherwise it is assigned to the .NET Framework so that it performs the tasks, however, I have not found anything about how to fix it.

If anyone has any form of help I would be forever grateful.

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you are trying to do!

Comment: Sounds like you are concatenating strings in a loop and fragmenting the heap.

Comment: I know arrays have a maximum size...

Comment: If you are parsing the XML by hand, instead of concatenating strings use an stringbuilder which is more efficient, that may solve your problem.

Comment: Also, what are you even using to parse? Linq-to-Xml would do a lot of the work for you, most likely.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671958/reading-large-xml-documents-in-net?

Comment: Maybe the file weighs too much :)

Comment: Read this, carefully: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx

Comment: You should post you code to get to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run it on a 64-bit machine and target your platform as 64-bit.

Go to your project properties -> build tab -> Platform target: change "Any CPU" to "x64".